# Where should I keep metadata for workflows in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to extend alfresco be adding metedata to workflows, such as adding a background image for each workflow. Note that I don't want to enter the data again for each instance, i.e. it is some part of the workflow definition.

Where do you suggest, that I keep the data, and how should I access the data? My own idea is to create a new table in the repo database, and put the metedata for each workflow in that table, and access that table directly in share.

Comment: I think you need to follow a proper training as an Alfresco engineer. Creating tables to store metadata isn't how Alfresco works.

Comment: @TahirMalik: OK. Whats your suggestion? Note that I want to store metadata for workflows, not metedata for documents. And what do you define as proper training for an 'Alfresco engineer'? People customizing a product or framework need not necessarily have to master that framework. They need only to know what is enough to do the customization whey want.

Comment: Making workflows isn't really customizing, it's just basic knowledge of the product and that is acquired by a training or following tutorials. If you had followed it, then you'd know that metadata of a workflow is already stored in Alfresco and you can reach for it without the use of creating tables or go anywhere near the DB.

Comment: Please read my problem statement again more carefully, specifically this sentence: 'Note that I don't want to enter the data again for each instance, i.e. it is some part of the workflow definition.'

Comment: I've got that sure, but asking something out of the blue on: what do you suggest, where to keep the data, how to access it. Means to me you don't really haven't done anything and want the rest to figure it out for you. So instead again, do some research on Alfresco and start with something and post your 'problem' so others can help. Have you seen questions with multiple answers? They aren't so short....

Comment: And of your 4 questions 2 are voted down, 1 is unanswered and you're registered only 12 days ago. Don't take me wrong, I'm criticising you because hopefully your next question will be better placed :).

Comment: The other question which was downvoted was a mistake. Read the appologies of the comment of the downvoter, and the other is related to you. I am reading Q/A here for more than two years! I know what can be asked! And my question is very clear.

Comment: I am actually requesting design / architecture, which people here consider completely valid. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49270/discussions-on-software-architecture-is-stackoverflow-appropriate-place) for a discussion on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you want a background image for each workflow type?

I would put that in configuration, which type uses which background image.

Then you need to fetch the configuration in a share-webscript (maybe modify an existing one) (js file). In the associated ftl you should write the background image

To begin with your could just leave the configuration part out and hardcode the different background images into the JS-file